# QWidgets added to grid layout are placed as if it was a vertical layout

Tags: qt, qwidget, qlayout

I am building an application that includes a scroll area that starts empty. Then, an unlimited number of different widgtes can be included at user request. As the widgets are not large, I would like them to be placed in a grid, organized in rows and columns. Ideally, the rows would be filled right to left, top to bottom.

I would like them to be placed like in the image below, where numbers indicate the order in which they are added:

[image]

However, what I get is this:

[image]

What I am doing is the following:

1. In the ui file I have a scroll area that includes a grid layout, with this setup:
   [image]
2. In the code, I add the widgets. I am actually using my own widget classes but the procedure is the following:

   ```
   QWidget *w1 = new QWidget(this);
   ui->layout_output_grid->addWidget(w1);
   QWidget *w2 = new QWidget(this);
   ui->layout_output_grid->addWidget(w2);
   QWidget *w3 = new QWidget(this);
   ui->layout_output_grid->addWidget(w3);
   QWidget *w4 = new QWidget(this);
   ui->layout_output_grid->addWidget(w4);
   QWidget *w5 = new QWidget(this);
   ui->layout_output_grid->addWidget(w5);
   ```

**Question**

Is there any way to do this?
As a workaround, I assume I could keep count of the widgets added and implement rows as different horizontal layouts but I would like to know if there is a solution to get Qt to place the widgets the way I want?

Comment: Are you looking for something like a [flow layout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which row, column and rowspan/columns the widget you want to add (1,2,3,4,5) must occupy.

Look for this overloaded function: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2

In this case you should do something like this:

```
QWidget *w1 = new QWidget(this);
ui->layout_output_grid->addWidget(w1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
QWidget *w2 = new QWidget(this);
ui->layout_output_grid->addWidget(w2, 0, 1, 1, 2);
QWidget *w3 = new QWidget(this);
ui->layout_output_grid->addWidget(w3, 1, 0, 1, 1);
QWidget *w4 = new QWidget(this);
ui->layout_output_grid->addWidget(w4, 1, 1, 1, 1);
QWidget *w5 = new QWidget(this);
ui->layout_output_grid->addWidget(w5, 1, 2, 1, 1);
```

Comment: This helps me a lot! However, ideally I would not need to keep count of the widgets added and their size.